# Why do we need to parenthesize the arguments in a function called by define?

Tags: c++, preprocessor

I was reading Effective C++: 55 ... and in Item no 2 .. there was this one line of code which I didn't understand

```
#define CALL_WITH_MAX(a, b) f((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

why do we need to parenthesize the arguments in the function called by define (here f() ) ?

Comment: macros are "dumb" lexical substitutions.   They can easily end up creating syntactic constructs you didn't intend.  Parenthesis make that not happen.

Comment: In particular they don't evaluate operands before substituting them into the expression, so you can get nasty operator precedence issues. This is can be seen with something like `#define SQUARED(x) x * x` because than `SQUARED(1 + 3)` is `1 + 3 * 1 + 3 == 7` instead of `16`.